# Is it possible to route my simple URL (without specifing the module, controller and action) in Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, router

I am using zend framework for my project and I have a requirement to route the path where I want it. For example:
I have a path www.example.com/module/controller/action1 and I want to internally route in to www.example.com/module/controller/action2.

But the main problem is I do not want to use the function in which I have to specify the module, controller and action [$this->_forward('action2', 'controller', 'module');], simply I something like this: $this->_forward('module/controller/action2');.

Please suggest me if anybody has its solution. its urgent need of my project.

Thanks,
Jitu

Comment: Can you explain why you want to have the url passed on? It is not possible for ZF to accept an url, because it requires the module/controller/action parameters. Otherwise, the url needs to be passed to the Router which can tell the module/controller/action. And that's a lot of overhead for a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

The controller method `_forward()` can accept only the action if it is in the same controller and module as the first action you are forwarding from.

So in your `action1Action()` method, you can simply call:

`$this->_forward('action2');`

If your second action is not in the same module/controller, you could subclass Zend_Controller_Action into your own "base" application controller that all your other action controllers inherit from (a good practice on ZF projects I find) and then create another one called `_forwardFromUrl()` or something like that, which breaks your URL apart and passes it to `_forward()` (or create an action controller helper if you just need this one extra thing).

This example is simplified and assumes your `$url` will always be in the format `module/controller/action`:

```
protected function _forwardFromUrl($url)
{
   $parts = array_reverse(explode("/",$url));
   $this->_forward($parts[0],$parts[1],$parts[2]);
}
```

Hope that helps!